# VSCode unable to autoimport python functions

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, python-poetry

I am currently able to use quick fix to auto import python functions from external typings such as `from typing import List`.

[Python module quick fix import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3m7F.png)

However, I am unable to detect local functions/classes for import. For example: If I have the data class `SampleDataClass` in `dataclasses.py`, and I reference it in a function in `test_file.py`, VSCode is unable to detect it and I have to manually type out the import path for the dataclass.

[Definition of dataclass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlXuJ.png)

[Reference to dataclass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRY6H.png)

I have the following extensions enabled:

- Python
- Pylance
- Intellicode

My settings.json includes:

```
{
  "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
  "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
  "python.analysis.indexing": true,
  "python.formatting.provider": "black",
  "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
  "python.analysis.autoSearchPaths": true,
  "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["~/Development/<django repo name>/server"],
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["~/Development/<django repo name>/server"],
  "vsintellicode.features.python.deepLearning": "enabled",
}
```

I am using poetry for my virtual environment which is located at `~/Development/<django repo name>/.venv`

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Describing the problem in detail will help others to help you solve the problem. Can you show the error interface or provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the latest versions for Pylance broke quick-fix imports and any extra path settings for VSCode. When I rolled back the version to `v2022.8.50` it now works again.

I filed an issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3353.

Answer (score 0):

According to an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3324) I raised in github earlier, the developer gave a reply.

Custom code will **not** be added to the autocomplete list at this time (unless it has already been imported). This is done to prevent users from having too many custom modules, which may lead to too long loading time.

If necessary, you can start a discussion in github and vote for it.

**Add:**

[image]

Comment: My phrasing could have been better. My actual issue is that I don't even get prompted for the quick fix to add the import. So I have to manually type out my imports every time.

Comment: I updated the description to be more clear.

Comment: I can get auto-complete. Are your two files in the same directory? I added my example to the answer

Comment: Yeah the files are in the same directory.

Comment: Looks like it was a new issue. Rolling back my VSCode extensions fixed it.